# How to plot all the sectioning levels using \ref{label}?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

In following MWE, the `\ref` command returns the actual numbering of the subsection it refers to (here "a" -- cf. red box on the picture below). How to make it to return "1.a"?

In more generic terms : **how to make `\ref` return the number of current (sub)section, but also the ones of higher hierarchical levels?**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}
    As we will see in §\ref{sec:interesting-subsection}, our work is amazing.
    \section{Section title}
            \subsection{Sub-section title} 
            \label{sec:interesting-subsection}
                    Trust me, I'm engineer.
\end{document}
```

[image: I want the 'a' become '1.a']

(Of course, I don't want nor to change the subsection numbering style (with `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}`), neither to add a label to the parent section and call `§\ref{sec:parent-section}\ref{sec:interesting-subsection}`.)

Comment: You should have a look at `scrjura`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a current scrartcl you can format the number independently from `\thesubsection`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\alph{subsection}\autodot\enskip}
\begin{document}
    As we will see in §\ref{sec:interesting-subsection}, our work is amazing.
    \section{Section title}
            \subsection{Sub-section title}
            \label{sec:interesting-subsection}
                    Trust me, I'm engineer.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is the trick I couldn't find, but was looking for. Thank you!